# How to show hover with mouseover on element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I am curently working on one Javascript to show hover when mouseover.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.playlogo').mouseover(function () {
    $('.company-image-overlay').show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('.company-image-overlay').hide();
});
});
</script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<li class="playlogo"><a href="videos/[blkfeatured_videos.indexer;block=div]/[blkfeatured_videos.title_seo;htmlconv=no;block=div]"><img src="./uploads/player_thumbs/[blkfeatured_videos.video_id;block=div].jpg" title="<!--[blkfeatured_videos.title;htmlconv=no;ope=max:50;maxhtml;block=div;comm]-->"/></a><div class="company-image-overlay"></div></li>
```

I have many `<li class="playlogo">` elements on this page.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.company-image-overlay {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background: transparent url(/images/play.png) no-repeat;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
}
```

The problem now is that when i mouseover one `<li class="playlogo">` it shows the hover efect on all other elements with `<li class="playlogo">`.

The question is - How i can make the Javascript show hover only on the one element on which i hover with my mouse at the moment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to `this` and get its children :

```
$(this).find('.company-image-overlay').show();
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But not it have other problem. Now it's showing the hover without hover on the element but when i hover twice it's getting okey. How i can fix this bug?

Comment: @TonnyStruck add in your css `.company-image-overlay` a `display : none;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the specific `.playlogo` that you're hovering, and then use `.children()` to traverse from within that context. * I'm using `.children()` because we're only traversing one level. Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jr6Vn/

```
$('.playlogo').each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).children('.company-image-overlay').show();
    });
    $(this).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).children('.company-image-overlay').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be able to accomplish this with CSS

```
.company-image-overlay{
    display:none;
}

.playlogo:hover .company-image-overlay{
     display:inherit;
}
```